# Values doesn't refresh on edit and save of lightning component

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

On click of edit page a lightning component opens up, And after save when it redirects from edit to the detail page , the latest changed data is visible only when refresh is done manually.

Below is my sample code. Though using the force refreshview also it doesn't work.

```
 action.setCallback(this,function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS" && value > -1  ) {
            window.close();
        }
        else if(state === "SUCCESS" && value === -1  ) {
             var address = '/lightning/r/GBM_Client_Plan__c/'+response.getReturnValue()+'/view';
            var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
            urlEvent.setParams({
                "url": address
            });
           // $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
            urlEvent.fire();
             $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
        }
            else if (state  ==="null" || state  ===undefined ) {
                this.handleException(component,response.getError());}
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comment. so in my case i was calling two event fire methods in my code. On debugging i discovered that only one event.fire is called.Hence the force refreshview was never called. So i re routed my logic to make use of the native javascript. 
Window.location.href - which navigates to the desired page and also refreshes it simulatenously

Answer (score 0):

force:refreshView was supposed to work.
See if this information helps: http://simpluslabs.com/working-and-usage-of-forcerefreshview-in-lightning/

debug the code to see if it is really going through this line(`$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire()`): [enter link description here](https://www.mstsolutions.com/technical/way-to-debug-salesforce-lightning-components/)

If it doesn't help, share the code.